# How to calculate size of nodes in bytes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a reference for the 'position' of a node from the  node and was wondering how I could go about doing that - should I get the html text somehow and calculate the length of the text (or would that mess things up if there were some chinese, etc characters in there because of the character encoding), or should I calculate the size of the nodes in bytes somehow. And how would I go about doing that? I was hoping to iterate through all the nodes and calculate the 'size' of each node, but I don't see any property like that in the nodes.

Sorry for my amateurish explanation, I am just getting started with JS as you can probably tell :)

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps a code snippet for a better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can use

```
$("selector").innerHeight()
```

and

```
$("selector").innerWidth()
```

to get the current width and height of a node.